# Move laravel 4.2 from localhost to shared, or not, web hosting

Tags: web-services, laravel, laravel-4, localhost

I'm trying to upload my working laravel web app from localhost to a web server, but I still have the same problem: white page. But if I put a call to phpinfo into index.php I can see the result. I've tried to keep the same directory structure of the original project, but when i navigate to myhost.com/app/public i see white page. I've also tried to move all content of public to upper dir, change the paths from bootstrap/paths.php of public var to '/..' and from index.php (removing ../ from require autoload.php and start.php), but same problem. At last,  I've tried to add this lines to .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^app/public 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/public/$1 [L]
```

...and another white page.

So I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: I've found the problem: the webhosting use an older php version (5.2).
So, what can I do to use my laravel app?

Answer (score 0):

The `public/` directory should not be inside of the `app/` directory.

If you're on a shared host you're probably on a virtual host.

All you should have to do is move your project, make sure the host has mod_rewrite enabled and `AllowOverride All` in the apache configuration (if apache).

And then use the .htaccess below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

# For all files not found in the file system, reroute the request to the
# "index.php" front controller, keeping the query string intact

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I always follow this little guide for putting a **laravel 4** installation on shared hosting, just make sure you got the right **.htaccess** and **the paths** are okay: http://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-on-a-shared-host

Answer (score -1):

On your shared host, do you have a controlpanel like DirectAdmin available?

Comment: This isn't an answer, and should be left as a comment on the original question.